# Find the density of $Y = X^n$for a positive integer $n$ when $X ∼ U(−1, 1)$.

Tags: probability

I find answer about the case that $X ∼ U(0, 1)$. But I have no idea when $X ∼ U(−1, 1)$.

Is it okay that I solve same way?

**My solution**
$\qquad\begin{align}F_Y(y)&=P(Y\le y)\\&=P(X^n\le y)\\&=P(-y^\frac{1}{n}\le X\le y^\frac{1}{n})\\&=\int_{-y^\frac{1}{n}}^{y^\frac{1}{n}}\frac{1}{2}dx\\&=y^\frac{1}{n}\\f_Y(y)&=\frac{1}{n}y^{\frac{1}{n}-1}\end{align}$

Where $-1\le y\le1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to discuss them separately,

If $n$ is even, and for $0\le y\le 1$

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X^n\le y)=P(-y^\frac{1}{n}\le X\le y^\frac{1}{n})$$

If $n$ is odd, and for $-1\le y\le 1$

$$F_Y(y)=P(Y\le y)=P(X^n\le y)=P(-1\le X\le y^\frac{1}{n})$$

Comment: Thank you for answer. But I wonder why the lower bound is -1 when n is odd while in the even case $-y^\frac{1}{n}$ not $0$?

Comment: @user170085 because when n is odd, $x^n$ is odd function, and is monotonic. While if n is even, $x^n$ is even function.